# Can I "Go to definition" for types displayed inside type hover layer in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I could swear I used to be able to do this...  I want to be able to navigate to the definition of types that are displayed inside VSCode's typescript hover layer for a variable.   I used to be able to press "CMD" and then the types inside the hover layer would appear underlined when I moused over them, and I could click them to open a buffer to their definition.

[Typescript hover layer where I want to choose "Go to Definition"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOHxb.png)

[image]

I have tried disabling all extensions, restarting, etc.  Searching web yields many unrelated results.  AI is not able to help, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No — type information in the *quick info* that's surfaced by the TypeScript language server in VS Code does not respond to click events by default. There is a GitHub issue about this: [microsoft/vscode#97704 — Allow cmd/ctrl-clicking in Intellisense tooltips](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97704).

From the documentation for [VS Code IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense):

> [image]
>
> When applicable, a language service will surface the underlying types in the quick info and method signatures. In the image above, you can see several `any` types. Because JavaScript is dynamic and doesn't need or enforce types, `any` suggests that the variable can be of any type.

---

You can use the [Go to Type Definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-type-definition) feature to navigate to the definition of the type of a symbol, and this action is bound to ctrl/cmd + click by default for the symbol itself.

Comment: Thank you.  I could have sworn I was able to do this when I first learned VS Code.